# Android APK file upgrade process

Tags: android, upgrade, apk

I was wandering if there is an API to upgrade an application to newer version without going through Android Market. Example I have a .apk file version 1.0 and I would like to upgrade it to version 2.0 programmatically. Bearing in mind I would prefer a method that does not override user's high score or data when doing application upgrade.

Thanks much

Comment: Do you mean something to automatically upload your update to the Android Market, or a sort of auto-updater to download and install the new version from within your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on a `Uri` pointing to the updated APK, also giving the `Intent` the magic MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`).

Comment: Note that this only works if the APK is already downloaded! If you try to do it to `http://` URIs you will get an `ActivityNotFoundException` which can be solved by removing the mime type.

Comment: @Timmmm: Correct. It only works with `file:///` `Uri` values, nothing else.